# how to put a custom view in a table row in android?

Tags: android

I am creating table rows programmatically and i want to put a view that i created before in a row. Is there any way to do it?

```
 for ( current = 0; current < rapor1.length; current++)
    {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setId(100+current);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

        TextView f1 = new TextView(this);
        f1.setId(200+current);
        f1.setText(rapor1[current]);
        f1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        f1.setWidth(100);
        tr.addView(f1);

       DrawView dv = new DrawView(this);
        tr.addView(dv);
```

it should be working but something is wrong.

Comment: What is wrong? Compilation Errors? Runtime error? Provide more info

Comment: it is not adding there. it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may helps. Just change this string:

```
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

And of course you need to set LayoutParams to any view that you want to show on your screen

Comment: well you haven't set layout params for textview and drawview, it may cause the problem, it's layout params should be written like `TableRow.LayoutParams` either

Comment: DrawView  dv = new DrawView(this);
            dv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(20, 20));
            tr.addView(dv);

i tried still not working...

Comment: DrawView  dv = new DrawView(this);
            tr.addView(dv, 100, 100);

it worked!